# show alert box with Text field in it

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I want to show a Alert Box with TextBox field in it, whenever the page loads. Something like this:

```
Enter Your Username: //Title
___________________  //TextBox field (value will be stored in var for later use)

                OK   //Button
```

I know

```
var username = "username";  //already entered message
alert(username);
```

How to achieve the above Alert Box? should I manually code it?
Giving an example in `jQuery` is preferable. I am trying to do this for my chat application where username is required to show in the chat. I searched alot but couldn't find any useful related to asp.net and jquery.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use good old JavaScript:

```
var text = prompt("prompt", "textbox's intial text");
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHD4D/)

Comment: Though I was preferring jQuery, I will go with this answer because it is one liner and simple. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Giving an example in jQuery is preferable.

[jQuery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) provides an aesthetic JavaScript Prompt, which is equally easy to call as JavaScripts `window.prompt` method:

```
//Simple Prompt
$.prompt('Example 1');

//Opacity of the modal
$.prompt('Example 3',{ opacity: 0.2 });

//Adding Callbacks
function mycallbackfunc(e,v,m,f){
alert('i clicked ' + v);
}

$.prompt('Example 8',{ callback: mycallbackfunc });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)
to show a form in a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to show a Alert Box with TextBox field in it,".   alert box with text field is not possible at all..(from what i have learnt till now).... u can use other jquery plugins like dialog

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

to do the same..

or the classic way using prompt

```
var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var msg = window.prompt("Write your name", "Name");
alert(msg);
});​
```