# HTML - Javascript - input condition

Tags: javascript, html, input

Ive been looking but cant seem to find much clarification...
I am creating a form -
If a user is to select an option for contact "email",
the user must enter a text value for email input type.

Here is a fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/4s3bLf65/

```
      if ($("input[name='option']").val()=='email') &&($("input[name='email1']").val() == '')
  {
    alert('Enter email');
                            return false;  
  }
```

I cant seem to figure out the proper syntax for the js...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show alert box with Text field in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599236/show-alert-box-with-text-field-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try that way:

```
if ($("input[name='option']:checked").val()=='email' && $("input[name='email1']").val() == '')
{
    alert('Enter email');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Syntax is always a pain for me =(

Answer (score 0):

- Add your code to a click handler or submit handler so it executes when the button is pressed.
- Your `if` had too many perentheses
- You were not getting the value of the `:checked` box.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[name="btn_submit"]').click(function() {
          if ($("input[name='option']:checked").val() == 'email' && $("input[name='email1']").val() == '') {
              alert('Enter email');
              return false;
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ojqa46a0/